# i don't get this line , marks_count[total_marks[i]]++; please, anyone describe it

Tags: c

I don't get this line: `marks_count[total_marks[i]]++;`. Please describe its meaning.

```
int i;   
int total_marks[] = {86, 78, 94, 68, 92, 78, 64, 62, 72, 61, 72, 66, 65, 65, 80, 72, 62, 68, 81, 62, 56, 68, 58, 56, 82, 70, 74, 78, 76, 84, 88, 73, 62, 66, 76, 70, 67, 65, 77, 63};   
int marks_count[101];   
for(i = 0; i < 101; i++) {   
    marks_count[i] = 0;   
}   
for(i = 0; i < 40; i++) {   
    marks_count[total_marks[i]]++;   
}   
for(i = 50; i <= 100; i++) {   
    printf("Marks: %d Count: %d\n", i, marks_count[i]);   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `total_marks` array holds all the marks that people got in the test (assuming it is a test, of course).

What:

```
marks_count[total_marks[i]]++;
```

does is to increment an array element corresponding to the mark somebody got. In other words, it's counting the number of results of each mark.

In more details:

```
// Initialise all counts to zero.

for(i = 0; i < 101; i++) {   
    marks_count[i] = 0;   
}   

// For each of forty results, increment the
// count corresponding to the result.

for(i = 0; i < 40; i++) {   
    marks_count[total_marks[i]]++;   
}
```

If, for example, the array was simply `{42, 7, 42}` (and the size corrected to three rather than forty), you'd end up with an array of mostly zeros, other than:

```
marks_count[7]  = 1
marks_count[42] = 2
```